# MacBook Pro running OS X lion stuck on boot screen

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, startup

My MacBook is stuck on the boot screen like this:

[image: Basic grey Mac boot screen with Apple logo and spinner]

I have tried multiple things such as launching it in safe mode and pressing some buttons as soon as the computer boot logo shows up.

Comment: You may be able to get more info about what's going on by starting the Mac in [verbose mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492) -- hold the Command and V keys as it starts up, and it'll switch to a text display of the startup process (instead of just showing a spinning gear icon under the Apple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me only in 2 cases:

- [Incompatible SSD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30216/11600) installed
- Hard drive failure

There is a good chance that if you leave your MBP running for a few hours like that it will end-up displaying a files not found logo.

The best way to test if it is a hard drive failure is to replace it or to connect an external hard drive and install Mac OS on it.